# Look for specific combinations across columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an R dataframe with specific combinations of characters (df1 below) and another dataframe with a list of sampleIDs and whether or not they have each character (df2). For each row (combination) in df1, I am trying to add sampleIDs if a sampleID in df2 contains all entries. The sampleID should be noted if it has all entries from one specific combination, and it doesn't matter if it has more than those entries. e.g. The same sampleID can appear in multiple rows of df1. (In the real dataset, not every row in df1 has exactly 3 entries.)

```
df1 <- data.frame(entry1 = c("A","B","C"),
                  entry2 = c("D","E","F"),
                  entry3 = c("G","H","I"))

df2 <- data.frame(sampleID = c("1001","1002","1003","1004","1005"),
                  "A" = c("A","0","0","A","A"),
                  "B" = c("B","B","B","0","0"),
                  "C" = c("0","0","0","C","C"),
                  "D" = c("D","0","D","0","0"),
                  "E" = c("E","E","0","0","0"),
                  "F" = c("0","0","0","F","F"),
                  "G" = c("G","0","0","G","0"),
                  "H" = c("H","H","H","H","0"),
                  "I" = c("0","0","I","O","0"))
```

The example output would look like this:

```
df1.2 <- data.frame(entry1 = c("A","B","C"),
                    entry2 = c("D","E","F"),
                    entry3 = c("G","H","I"),
                    sampleID.1 = c("1001","1001",""),
                    sampleID.2 = c("","1002",""))
```

such that row/combination1 is achieved by sampleID 1001, row/combination2 by sampleIDs 1001 and 1002, and no sampleIDs have combination3.

I was trying a for loop iterating over rows in df2 but couldn't get it to correctly add the sampleID to df1. There may be a better strategy entirely. I'm also open to transforming either df.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were interested in using a loop, you could try the following.

A nested loop could be constructed that will go through rows of both data.frames and store in a `list` the row number and `sampleID` where all values of `df1` are in a row of `df2`.

```
lst <- list()
ctr <- 1

for (i in seq_len(nrow(df1))) {
  for (j in seq_len(nrow(df2))) {
    if (all(df1[i, ] %in% df2[j, names(df2) != "sampleID"])) lst[[ctr]] <- list(i, df2[j, "sampleID"]); ctr <- ctr + 1
  }
}
```

Then, you can convert the `list` to a `matrix` with 2 columns representing the row number `rn` where matched and the `sampleID`. You can use `pivot_wider` to put into wide form and then join back to your original `df1` data.

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(matrix(unlist(lst), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(NULL, c("rn", "sampleID")))) %>%
  mutate(x = row_number(), .by = "rn") %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = rn, values_from = sampleID, names_from = x, names_prefix = "sampleID.") %>%
  right_join(mutate(df1, rn = as.character(seq.int(nrow(df1))))) %>%
  relocate(starts_with("sampleID"), .after = last_col())
```

**Output**

```
  rn    entry1 entry2 entry3 sampleID.1 sampleID.2
  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>      <chr>     
1 1     A      D      G      1001       NA        
2 2     B      E      H      1001       1002      
3 3     C      F      I      NA         NA
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to

- `cross_join` the data
- check the condition
- `pivot_wider` to create the sampleID table
- then finalize by cleaning up the names with `rename_with`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

cross_join(df1, df2) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(res = all(across(starts_with("entry")) %in% across(A:I))) %>% 
  select(1:4, res) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(res | (row_number() == 1 & !any(res)), 
    .by = c(entry1, entry2, entry3)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = sampleID, values_from = sampleID,
    names_glue = "{.value}_{.name}", values_fill = "") %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(replace(across(starts_with("sample")), !res, "")) %>% 
  rename_with(function(x) sub("_100", ".", x)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-res)
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  entry1 entry2 entry3 sampleID.1 sampleID.2
  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr>      <chr>     
1 A      D      G      "1001"     ""        
2 B      E      H      "1001"     "1002"    
3 C      F      I      ""         ""
```